# Can't put WAMP server online due to internal error

Tags: windows-7, wamp

I have WAMP server set up on my Windows 7 64-bit computer. When trying to put the server online, I get the following error:

> internal error, service has not been started

What might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe go to the services area and start the service.